# How to set a field equal to a related model's foreign key on save() Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, wagtail

I have three models, `LocationPage`, `Customer`, and `WorkOrder`.  `LocationPage` has a `city_name` CharField.

`Customer` and `WorkOrder` both have a `customer_city` and `service_city` ForeignKey to `LocationPage`, respectively.

On creation of a `WorkOrder` when `service_city` is left blank I want to update `service_city` with the same ForeignKey as belongs to `Customer`'s `customer_city`.

However, when I try this, I get an `OperationalError at /admin/workorders/workorder/create/ table workorders_workorder has no column named service_city_id`

***locations.models.LocationPage***

```py
class LocationPage(Page):
    """Location page model."""
    location_city = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False) 
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Location Page"
        verbose_name_plural = "Location Pages"

    def get_context(self, request):
        context = super().get_context(request)

        return context
```

***workorders.models.Customer***

```py
class Customer(index.Indexed, ClusterableModel, models.Model):
    customer_city = models.ForeignKey('locations.LocationPage', on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name="City", related_name="cust_city")
    referred_from = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=REFERRAL_CHOICES, default='g')
    created = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, default=timezone.now())
    modified = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Customer"
        verbose_name_plural = "Customers"

    def get_context(self, request):
        context = super().get_context(request)
        return context

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.created = timezone.now()
        self.modified = timezone.now()
        return super(Customer, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

***workorders.models.WorkOrder***

```py
class WorkOrder(index.Indexed, ClusterableModel, models.Model):
    """Workorder model."""

    same_as_customer_address = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False, verbose_name="Same as Customer")
    service_city = models.ForeignKey('locations.LocationPage', on_delete=models.PROTECT, help_text="Dallas", verbose_name="City", blank=True, null=False)

    related_customer = ParentalKey('Customer', related_name='workorders', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, verbose_name="Customer")

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.same_as_customer_address:
            self.service_address = self.related_customer.customer_address
            self.service_city = self.related_customer.customer_city
            self.service_state = self.related_customer.customer_state
            self.service_zip = self.related_customer.customer_zip
        if self.service_address is None:
            self.service_address = self.related_customer.customer_address
        if self.service_city is None:
            self.service_city = self.related_customer.customer_city
        if self.service_state is None:
            self.service_state = self.related_customer.customer_state
        if self.service_zip is None:
            self.service_zip = self.related_customer.customer_zip
        if not self.id:
            self.created = timezone.now()
            self.modified = timezone.now()
        return super(WorkOrder, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

***Traceback***

```py
Internal Server Error: /admin/workorders/workorder/create/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/joseph/Python/PC_Work_Order/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/joseph/Python/PC_Work_Order/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 413, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: table workorders_workorder has no column named service_city_id

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/joseph/Python/PC_Work_Order/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/joseph/Python/PC_Work_Order/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/joseph/Python/PC_Work_Order/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/joseph/Python/PC_Work_Order/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wagtail/admin/urls/__init__.py", line 110, in wrapper
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/joseph/Python/PC_Work_Order/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wagtail/admin/auth.py", line 188, in decorated_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/joseph/Python/PC_Work_Order/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wagtail/contrib/modeladmin/options.py", line 360, in create_view
    return view_class.as_view(**kwargs)(request)
  File "/Users/joseph/Python/PC_Work_Order/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/joseph/Python/PC_Work_Order/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wagtail/contrib/modeladmin/views.py", line 646, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/joseph/Python/PC_Work_Order/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/joseph/Python/PC_Work_Order/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/joseph/Python/PC_Work_Order/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wagtail/contrib/modeladmin/views.py", line 74, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/joseph/Python/PC_Work_Order/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 98, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/joseph/Python/PC_Work_Order/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 142, in post
    return self.form_valid(form)
  File "/Users/joseph/Python/PC_Work_Order/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wagtail/contrib/modeladmin/views.py", line 169, in form_valid
    instance = form.save()
  File "/Users/joseph/Python/PC_Work_Order/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modelcluster/forms.py", line 348, in save
    instance = super(ClusterForm, self).save(commit=(commit and not save_m2m_now))
  File "/Users/joseph/Python/PC_Work_Order/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 460, in save
    self.instance.save()
  File "/Users/joseph/Python/PC_Work_Order/Repairitor/workorders/models.py", line 190, in save
    return super(WorkOrder, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/joseph/Python/PC_Work_Order/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modelcluster/models.py", line 196, in save
    super(ClusterableModel, self).save(update_fields=real_update_fields, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/joseph/Python/PC_Work_Order/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 753, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "/Users/joseph/Python/PC_Work_Order/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 790, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "/Users/joseph/Python/PC_Work_Order/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 895, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "/Users/joseph/Python/PC_Work_Order/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 933, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "/Users/joseph/Python/PC_Work_Order/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/joseph/Python/PC_Work_Order/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1254, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "/Users/joseph/Python/PC_Work_Order/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1397, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/joseph/Python/PC_Work_Order/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/joseph/Python/PC_Work_Order/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/Users/joseph/Python/PC_Work_Order/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/Users/joseph/Python/PC_Work_Order/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/joseph/Python/PC_Work_Order/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/Users/joseph/Python/PC_Work_Order/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/joseph/Python/PC_Work_Order/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 413, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: table workorders_workorder has no column named service_city_id
```

I'm really not sure why this error is being thrown, do I need to just add _id to service_city in my WorkOrder object?

Comment: Did you properly migrate your models?

Comment: Just wiped my database and re-migrated, it works now, thanks.  How should I go about migrating something like this properly in the future?

Comment: the main problem is what to do with the *exiting* records. You can make your field `NULL`able and thus use `NULL` for the existing, or provide a default value for the `ForeignKey`, but that of course all depends on *how* you want to migrate.

Comment: So in this case, I had previously defined customer_city and service_city as CharFields, if I were operating on an active database I guess the best option would be to allow `NULL` and set default to `NULL`, as defaulting to a random city would unnecessarily correlate data with the wrong ForeignKey?